# ARM Cortex M4 - What happens to SysTick interrupt request when PRIMASK is set to 1?

Tags: arm, semaphore, interrupt, rtos, cortex-m

I'm learning about RTOS and I'm at a section talking about Semaphores. The book implements a spin-lock semaphore, but I'm having trouble understanding what happens with SysTick, which is used to implement the context switching.

```
 void OS_Wait(int32_t *s){
  while( (*s) == 0 )
  {
       EnableInterrupts(); //Does SysTick "wait" until this line?
       Disableinterrupts();
  }
  (*s) = (*s) - 1;
  EnableInterrupts();
}
```

EnableInterrupts() is an assembly subroutine

```
 EnableInterrupts
  CPSIE I
  BX LR
```

My other ARM book says the equivalent code for CPSIE I is

```
MOVS r0, #0
MSR PRIMASK, r0
```

I asked this question somewhere else and my understanding from one of the answers is, the RIS value for a particular interrupt stays high until it's serviced, since they have to be set to 0 in their handler, so the requests kind of "wait" until interrupts are enabled again. I'm not sure if this is correct or not. What happens with SysTick? It doesn't have a RIS bit that requests it's handler. So, what exactly happens to SysTick while the interrupts are disabled? I read the reference manual for my board (TM4C123) and it says the STCTRL register COUNT bit is raised each time an interrupt should occur. Is this it's equivalent RIS bit? The reference manual doesn't explicitly says so. Thank you!

Edit: I went over the reference manual. PRIMASK takes a value of 1 to disable all exceptions with configurable priority, so the code from earlier is a mistake I think. It should be a 1.

```
MOVS r0, #1
MSR PRIMASK, r0
```

Edit: Fixed the typo.

Comment: In `int32_t *2` `2` is not a valid symbol name.  You need to be sure you post real code - it is very difficult to answer a question when it is clear the code is invalid, and therefore not identical to the code you are asking the question about..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. It's not asking a question about the code though, I'm just asking what happens in the hardware.

Comment: Just to elaborate more: I'm learning all of this straight from the book. I haven't done any programming on what I've learned about semaphore. But I'm confused about how SysTick behaves when interrupts are disabled. The loop reenables them, and I think SysTick "waits" for that line of code. But I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: The systick interrupt asserts when it asserts at the rollover point.  Whether or not the core lets it in has to do with the enable.  if pending then sure when enabled it will then go in.

Comment: As a side-note, as an ARM-specific spin-lock this kind of sucks.  The exclusive access instructions (LDREX, STREX, CLREX) in Thumb-2 are designed to support exactly this kind of code without disabling interrupts, and are to be preferred for this reason.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

arm docs state

```
The CPSIE i instruction is equivalent to writing a 0 into PRIMASK.
The CPSID i instruction is equivalent to writing a 1 into PRIMASK.
The CPSIE f instruction is equivalent to writing a 0 into FAULTMASK.
The CPSID f instruction is equivalent to writing a 1 into FAULTMASK.
```

Just try it...

```
.equ GPIOEBASE, 0x40021000
.equ RCCBASE  , 0x40023800
.equ STK_BASE , 0xE000E000

.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word systick_handler


.thumb_func
reset:
    ldr r0,=RCCBASE
    ldr r1,[r0,#0x30]
    ldr r2,=0x00000010
    orr r1,r2
    str r1,[r0,#0x30]

    ldr r0,=GPIOEBASE

    ldr r1,[r0,#0x00]
    ldr r2,=0x00000003
    bic r1,r2
    ldr r2,=0x00000001
    orr r1,r2
    str r1,[r0,#0x00]

    ldr r1,[r0,#0x04]
    ldr r2,=0x00000001
    bic r1,r2
    str r1,[r0,#0x04]

    ldr r1,=0x00000001
    str r1,[r0,#0x18]

    ldr r2,=STK_BASE
    ldr r3,=0x00004;
    str r3,[r2,#0x10]
    ldr r3,=0x10000;
    str r3,[r2,#0x14]
    ldr r3,=0x0000;
    str r3,[r2,#0x18]
    ldr r3,=0x00007;
    str r3,[r2,#0x10]

    ldr r3,=0
    msr PRIMASK,r3

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
systick_handler:
    ldr r1,=0x00010000
    str r1,[r0,#0x18]
    b .
.align
.word 0x12345678
.end
```

led turns on

```
ldr r3,=1
msr PRIMASK,r3
```

led stays off

```
cpsie i
```

led on

```
cpsid i
```

led off

the cpsid/cpsie are small single instructions

```
 8000076:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000078:   f383 8810   msr PRIMASK, r3
 800007c:   b662        cpsie   i
 800007e:   2301        movs    r3, #1
 8000080:   f383 8810   msr PRIMASK, r3
 8000084:   b672        cpsid   i
```

I would go with cpsid/cpsie.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your advise earlier and wrote in CPSID and CPSIE for a program I wrote before for SysTick. When I wrote just CPSID before the loop, it wasn't going into the handler because the external LED didn't blink. When I added both CPSID and CPSIE it blinked. Another question I had was if this causes jitters? I guess it's something I could check myself, but I'd need a logic analyzer?